# Обнуление указателя внутри функции

Tags: c, указатели

Есть некая структура

```
typedef struct db db;

struct db {
    int nameLen;
    char * name;
    int count;
    int rowId;
    int maxRows;
    record * rows;
};
```

В самой программе она объявлена так:

```
db * DB;
```

Есть функция :

```
void close (db * DB)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < DB->count; i++)
        free(DB->rows[i].nums);

    free(DB->rows);
    free(DB->name);
    free(DB);
    DB = NULL;
}
```

Вызываю её так (printf для вывода адреса указателя):

```
printf("%i \n", DB);

close(DB);

printf("%i \n", DB);
```

Проблема в том, что указатель не сбрасывается в NULL, выводимое значение до вызова close(DB) и после одинаково. Что я делаю не так, и как будет правильнее обнулить указатель DB внутри функции, если такое возможно?

Answer (score 5):

Вы не можете так обнулить указатель, т.к. в функцию передается только *значение указателя*, функция не имеет доступа к переменной, откуда взято это значение.

Варианты решения:

1. Не "запариваться" и обнулять значение указателя самостоятельно после выхода из функции
2. Передавать в функцию указатель на указатель, тогда можно будет изменить значение исходной переменной (см. ответ Vlad from Moscow).
3. Возвращать из функции NULL и присваивать это значение исходной переменной: `DB = close(DB);` В данном случае в этом нет особого смысла, но в других случаях возврат нового значения указателя позволяет избежать необходимости передачи двойного указателя через аргументы функции.
4. Если вы пишете на С++, то можно передавать ссылку на указатель. Отличие от вашего примера будет только в сигнатуре функции close: `void close (db * & DB)`. Работать будет именно так, как вы и хотели.

Comment: Да, извините, язык не указал, это Си

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы изменить значение объекта, используемого как аргумент функции, его следует передавать по ссылке.

В этом случае ваша функция будет выглядеть как

```
void close (db * *DB)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < ( *DB )->count; i++)
        free( ( *DB )->rows[i].nums);

    free( ( *DB )->rows);
    free( ( *DB )->name);
    free( *DB);
    *DB = NULL;
}
```

и вызываться как

```
close( &DB );
```

Comment: Это не передача по ссылке, это передача двойного указателя.

Comment: @insolor В языке C это как раз называется передача по ссылке.

Comment: Отнюдь. В Си это называют передачей двойного указателя, или указателя на указатель, но никак не ссылки. Ссылка - это понятие из С++, если переносить его в Си, чтобы назвать ей указатель, то будет каша.

Comment: @insolor Стандарт C "A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type."

Comment: Здесь дается определение указателя, как объекта, чье значение предоставляет ссылку на другой объект. Из этого не следует, что указатель в Си можно называть указатель ссылкой, либо передачу указателя передачей по ссылке.

Comment: @insolor Из этого следует общепринятое понятие передачи аргументов по ссылке в языке программирования C. Ваша ошибка состоит в том, что вы смешиваете C терминологию с терминологией C++.

Comment: Я, пожалуй, воздержусь от дальнейшей дискуссии. Мое мнение таково: так как "миры" Си и С++ довольно тесно связаны, то во избежание недоразумений не нужно называть передачу указателя передачей по ссылке.

Comment: @insolor Например, в C# тоже есть понятие ссылки. Но оно не имеет ничего общего с понятием ссылки в C++. Из этого не следует, что либо в C# либо в C++ нельзя использовать этот термин. Каждый язык имеет свою терминологию и семантическое значение схожих терминов.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31267/discussion-between-insolor-and-vlad-from-moscow).